# Bowser for iOS getUserMedia is undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, webrtc, bowser

I'm trying to get WebRTC to work with the [Bowser](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/bowser) browser for iOS. But whatever I try `navigator.getUserMedia` is undefined.

I'm testing the page on an iPhone6 running iOS 8.3.

This is how I've set it up:

```
var localMediaStream;

navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

window.onload = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById('video');

    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(stream) {
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

        localMediaStream = stream;
    }, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
    });
};
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'navigator.getUserMedia')
```

If I don't feature-detect and use `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` directly (which is as I understand it the method that should exist in Bower) I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
```

inside onload

But for me it doesn't work when you open the page for the first time.
After page refresh it works.

UPD: It's due to the fact that Bowser's javascript was injected too late (or not injected at all). It was a iOs's webview problem. But bowser's team are saying that they have replaced it with the new control not web view but the newer one (don't remember the name, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(..)
```

should be fully supported by Safari 11 and up. It can be only accessed from a SSL domain though, so if developing locally, try to add a `https://` prefix to your alias.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia